# How does Cole get from the First World War to 1996?

Tags: plot-explanation, 12-monkeys

In Twelve Monkeys, Cole is repeatedly sent back in time, and after some period disappears and returns to the future.

Most times we see him back in the "interrogation room" strapped into that chair. But the second time he appears during World War I, where he gets shot in the leg. Next thing we know he's in 1996 where he kidnaps Railley.

The confusion I have is that in 1996 he still has the bullet in his leg - so if he returned to the future as normal, surely he would have received medical treatment before being sent back? Or did he somehow go straight from WWI to 1996?

Comment: I think it was a glitch and he was then zapped straight to 1996. I don't remember anyone explaining exactly *how* their time machine works anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Science ain't exact science with these clowns.*

Probably when the other guy in the past returned he immediately told the scientists about Cole, and they jumped him from WWI to 1996. He has the tracker in his tooth, so presumably he doesn't have to report back home each time, they can jump him from any point *A* to any point *B*. Since they likely didn't know he was injured, he was just sent to 1996 immediately.

Comment: While these are logical answers, why didn't they zap him to 1996 when he was in 1990, if they knew where he was because of a tracker?